# Magento 2 GuzzleHttp\Client and CuRl in Controller Not Working

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, guzzle

I am working on the integration of the Point Of Sale System with Magento 2 shop whenever the user click add to cart button API will hit that API will check the stock in POS if the requested product quantity from the user is available in POS(point of sale) Stock or not.

```
 $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
 $response = $http->get('http://poswebpoint.co/magentos/getstock/'.$websiteId.'/'.$sku, [
    'headers' => [
    'Accept'  => 'application/json',
 ],]);
```

Now, this code works fine in my Magento custom APIs but I want to make an API  call in \magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.PHP but unfortunately, it's not working.

Comment: where is the code of the API call for \magento\module-checkout\Controller\Cart\Add.php?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$websiteId = '<your web-site Id>';
$sku = '<your product SKU>';
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, 'http://poswebpoint.co/magentos/getstock/'.$websiteId.'/'.$sku, [
            'headers'   => [
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: Is this `new new` normal?

Comment: @bfontaine that was a typo mistake. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @VishalThakur thanks